# Unicast message in GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, unicast

I have one USRP B210 and E312 and all the message transferred between them are via the broadcast message.

Is there any way to transmit a unicast message (point to point) in GNURadio?

If yes, can you please help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing GNU Radio with something it is not:

GNU Radio is a framework for designing signal processing flow graphs. It is especially useful for processing digital radio signals.

Whether a message is "unicast" or "broadcast" or whatever isn't anything that GNU Radio is concerned with. You'd typically just analyze a packet that you received to determine whether it was meant for you.

GNU Radio isn't something that you typically use to implement a *network layer*. Mostly, you do *physical layer* signal processing. As soon as you have packets of bits, you usually leave GNU Radio. Your problem arises from a misunderstanding of what GNU Radio does (and maybe, software defined radio in general).

Comment: Thank you @Marcus. Appreciate your response.
I am completely new to the GNURadio world and its probably my lack of understanding on how GNURadio works, creates the confusion.

As you mentioned GNURadio works on the physical layer, can you help me to find out examples of what kind of library I can use on top of it to send/receive point to point communication.

Comment: The Linux kernel has a network stack. You could just broadcast IP packets and let your OS decide whether they are meant for the individual receivers.

Comment: Thanks again @Marcus, I will try the kernel network stack and create a virtual interface over it. 
have a great new year!

Answer (score 0):

I found a great library, gr-mac which can handle the broadcast and unicast messaging above the gnuradio.

https://github.com/jmalsbury/gr-mac

I hope it will be helpful to other new gnuradio users like me.